# Change MailItem pictogram

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I've created an outlook plugin to add mailitems to my program.

Now it would be nice the icon (pictogram) of the mail changes after i added it in the software. So you could see which mails are added into the program and which not.

Is that possible?

(I created the plugin with AddInExpress in Visual Studio 2010, c#)

Answer (score 0):

The icons for items displayed in an Outlook folder can only be customized if you are using custom forms.  You can choose a custom display icon in the properties for the custom form.